# Responding with a pre-defined message in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation

I am trying to be able to reply to an email with a pre-defined message. Every day, I get asked to do the same tasks and I have to reply to each with exactly the same email, similar to:

> Hi,
>   I received your email, I have now started the task for you.
>   Regards,
>   Dave

Tutorials I have found using the email template is more about starting a new email as opposed to replying (as it doesn't appear to keep the thread).

In my ideal world, I would like to click reply and insert a pre-written message.

The only way I've worked out how to do this is to 'cheat' some what and use the signature as the entire email response (and actually does the job very well other than leaving a space above my reply)

I have found similar questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/87754/how-to-set-my-custom-template-oft-as-a-default-template-in-outlook-2007) and [other websites](http://www.howtogeek.com/97859/how-to-create-and-use-templates-in-outlook-2010/) but have had no luck, nor have I from my own Google searches.

Does any one have any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Outlook 2007 or 2010, under the *Insert* tab of the ribbon you can use *Quick Parts* to enter text.

See: [Create reuseable text blocks for e-mail messages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-reuseable-text-blocks-for-e-mail-messages-HA010208653.aspx)

> The Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Quick Parts feature provides building blocks, reusable pieces of content or other e-mail message parts that are stored in galleries. You can access and reuse the building blocks at any time. You can also save building blocks and distribute them with templates so that other users can use the building blocks you created.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2010 Quick Steps is the solution to your problem.  Once you have set up a new one with your default text then all future email replies will be just one click.

If you are using an earlier version then explore AutoText.  Save your autotext then insert it into your email reply easily.  Just type 4+ characters of the autotext name and press enter (or use F3 key to insert).